# How to make a mongodb field receive either an empty array or a unique string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

There is such a model:

```js
import {Schema, model} from "mongoose";

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
warranty: {type: Number, required: true},
serial: [
    { type: String,  unique: true, required: true },
],
})

export default model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

I want this implementation:

If the serial field is empty, then I need to be able to add as many such records as I like.

```json
{ "product": { name: "hp pavilion1", warranty: 1, serial: [] } }
```

If the serial field is not empty, then strings must arrive and they must be unique, that is, if there is a record with the serial array, then there must be unique strings in it and so that in other records I cannot add the same values ​​as in the previous ones.

```json
{ "product": { name: "hp pavilion", warranty: 1, serial: [ "0EG118439X", "4UY113239E" ] } }
```

How can I implement this?

In the first case, I create one record, and then, if I want to leave the serial field empty, I get an error: `MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.products index: serial_1 dup key: { serial: undefined }`

Comment: Manually recreate the unique index on the database and make it partial as well. The partial index filter condition should be that the field exists. (If there's a way to express that in the mongoose schema then of course you can do it there instead. I'm just not sure if you can via that route, but I know it can be done in the database directly)